# How to insert in MYSQL with foreign key errors

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have created a table but when i try to insert values I get an error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`classicmodels`.`complaints`, CONSTRAINT `complaints_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeHandling`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerNumber`))

I'm not entirely sure what this means so an explanation would be very helpful! Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE `complaints` (
  `complaintNumber` INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `orderNumber`  INT,
  `employeeHandling` INT NOT NULL,
  `startDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `closeDate` DATE,
  `complaintType` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `details`    TEXT,
  `resolution` TEXT,
  `status` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`complaintNumber`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`employeeHandling`) REFERENCES customers (`customerNumber`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`customerNumber`) REFERENCES employees (`employeeNumber`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES orders (`orderNumber`)
  );

INSERT INTO complaints
VALUES
(NULL, 173, NULL, 1323, '2005-03-27', NULL, 'Late Shipment', 'Customer claims shipment came in 2 weeks late.  Requests discount/partial refund.', NULL, 'New'),
(NULL, 260, 10283, 1323, '2004-09-18', '2004-09-22', 'Damaged Shipment', 'Motorcycle had broken axle.  Requests replacement, partial refund.', 'Axle sent and installed.  Customer took $1000 refund', 'Closed'),
(NULL, 385, 10108, 1621, '2003-04-22', '2003-04-23', 'Missing Item', 'Customer claims item not included in shipment.  Requests shipment.', 'Customer miscounted shipment stock.  No action required.', 'Closed'),
(NULL, 471, 10265, 1611, '2004-07-10', '2004-08-10', 'Unclear', 'Customer disatisfied with shipment quality(?), though inventory not damaged.  Requests refund.', 'Customer failed to provide specific reasons.  Complaint ticket closed after 1 month of idle time.', 'Closed');
```

Comment: The value that you are insering to column `employeeHandling` needs to exist in table `customers`  beforehand.

Comment: I do have a customerNumber column with values that exists in customers already though @GMB

Comment: Shouldn't employeeHandling reference the employees table and customerNumber reference the customers table?

Comment: Yup that was it! Silly me. @HoneyboyWilson